# Limit solving seems too trial-and-error like

Tags: limits

I'm trying to get back into mathematics since my freshman year of college and am looking into limits and derivatives. I still understand the concepts, but forget how to find them.

So when learning how to find limits, I'm seeing that there's different ways to do it depending on what type of equation you are using like described in [this article](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/calculus/how-to-find-the-limit-of-a-function-algebraically/).

I am a computer science graduate and this seems way to much like trial and error ("If you notice such and such about the equation, try this way. But if you notice such and such, try this way instead"). However, calculators don't "notice" things about equations without a huge performance cost. So I'm struggling because I feel like there should be a more mathematical, absolute way of finding the limit of an equation.

Is there such a way? Or are we stuck with "try **_ if _**" type of methodologies for finding limits? Maybe another way to word the question is how would a computer be programmed to do it?

Comment: If there were a generic way then you would not need Newton's method or others to approximate a root, you could just compute the root from the recursion formula. But see Aitken's delta-squared process, Wynn's epsilon method and other acceleration methods that try to exploit structure in the convergent sequence.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for the exact value then you can directly plugin a value near the neighborhood. For example, you can approximate the derivative limit as:

$f'(a) = \lim \limits_{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \approx  \dfrac{f(a+0.0001)-f(a)}{0.0001} $

---

Letting $f(x) = \sin(x)$, the derivative at $x=0$ is approximately
$$ \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{x-0}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \approx  \dfrac{\sin(0+0.0001)}{0.0001}\approx 1.000$$

Comment: I am looking for an exact value.